# Are methyl n-propyl ether and methyl iso-propyl ether metamers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

Are methyl n-propyl ether and methyl iso-propyl ether metamers?
It says so [here](http://chem-guide.blogspot.in/2010/04/introduction-nomenclature.html).

So the difference must be in number of carbon atoms or the distribution?

Definition(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metamerism)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism I agree with @lighthart. Metamerism seem to be a limited definition of isomerism. As so it's chosen to be obsolete, you mustn't worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

The term metamer is equivalent to isomer.  Isomers differ in connectivites of atoms between molecules with the identical number and type of atoms.

Methyl *n*-propoyl Ether and methyl *iso*-propyl ether have the same numbers of carbon, oxygen and hydrogen atoms.

As an aside, I have never heard the term metamer before, I expect it is archaic.

Comment: Did you check that link? It has a definition.

Comment: Neither have I. It isn't in the Gold Book either.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metamerism @KlausWarzecha

Comment: @ChemExchange Irrelevant! No IUPAC, no cigar.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Okay

Comment: I think metamer has an interesting specification: it has to have the same molecular formula **and** the same functional group. While we could just say "isomeric ethers" or something, I think it's a cool concept, but I'll probably never use it, and it doesn't make much difference as far as this question goes. Now if the question had been about 1-methoxypropane and 2-methyl-1-propanol, that would come into play.

Answer (score 5):

Compounds having the same molecular formula but different number of carbon atoms ( alkyl groups) on either side of functional group ( i.e., $\ce{-O-,-S-, -NH-, -C(=O)-}$) are called metamers and the phenomenon is called metamerism. metamerism occurs amongst the members of the same homologus family.

For example:

- $\ce{CH3CH2-O-CH2CH3}$ is a metamer of $\ce{CH3-O-CH2CH2CH3}$ OR $\ce{CH3-O-CH(CH3)2}$
- $\ce{CH3CH2COCH2CH3}$ is a metamer of $\ce{CH3COCH2CH2CH3}$ OR $\ce{CH3COCH(CH3)2}$

It may be noted that metamers may also be position isomers, e.g., pentan-2-one and pentan-3-one may be regarded as position isomers as well as metamers.

Comment: Quoting from Wikipedia without mentioning the source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism

Answer (score 1):

It is a type of positional isomerism in which functional group changes its position in the backbone of parent chain,methyl propyl ether and methylisoptopyl ether are metamers from Above def.