# What are the metamers of penta-1,2-diene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, structural-formula

First of all, are there any metamers for dienes? If there are any, how can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Consider *metamer* to be a different word for *isomer*, as noted by [Lighthart](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27948/are-methyl-n-propyl-ether-and-methyl-iso-propyl-ether-metamers):

> The term metamer is equivalent to isomer...As an aside, I have never heard the term metamer before, I expect it is archaic.

And, according to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/diene), consider a diene to be:

> a hydrocarbon that contains two carbon-to-carbon double bonds in its molecules.

There are too many diene isomers to be listed here ($\ce{C5H8}$ has many atoms), but you can begin by changing the numbers in the name to generate different Lewis structures.

*Penta-1,2-diene:*

[image]

*Penta-1,4-diene:*

[image]

This is just one structure. Try *cis* vs. *trans*, position isomers, etc. You may think of many more.