# Metamerism in amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

I came across a question where $\ce{R-CH2-NH2}$ and $\ce{R-NH-CH3}$ are considered as functional group isomers but not as metamers.

If I'm not wrong, metamers compounds which have same molecular formula but different number of carbon atoms on a functional group (for example, $\ce{CH3-CH2-O-CH2-CH3}$ and $\ce{CH3-O-CH2-CH2-CH3}).$

So, shouldn't the compounds given in start of the question be metamers considering the fact that the '$\ce{NH}$' has different number of carbon atoms on either side in the two compounds, and if not, why so?

Comment: Then shouldn’t ethanol and dimethyl ether be metamers as well...but they are not. [Compounds  having the same molecular formula but different number of carbon atoms (alkyl groups) on either side of functional group (i.e., -O-,-S-, -NH-, -C(=O)-) are called metamers and the phenomenon is called metamerism.]- Wikipedia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the correct definition for metamers (or metamerism)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117674/which-is-the-correct-definition-for-metamers-or-metamerism)